# Bootstrap navbar with image on two rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please help.
I need to make the same construction:

```
|           |   Menu item1 | Menu item2    
|   Image   |____________________________________________________________
|           |   Some static text
__________________________________________________________________________
```

With bootstrap navbar class.
I can't understand how to split image on two rows without loose a functionality.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? any code?

Comment: Please provide relevant codes that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with some `Flexbox` and media queries [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/538/)

```css
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .two-rows-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want two rows with three columns where the item in the first column of the first row fits into both rows. The best way to do that would be nesting. for an example, say you have a row with two columns (col-md-3 and col-md-9). In the first column (col-md-3), you would have a image. In the second column (col-md-9), you would have a row with static text underneath. Illustration:

---

```
Image     | First | nested | row
(col-md-3)| ---------------------
          | Text
          | ---------------------
```

Code example:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- The first column where the image will be -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="your-img.jpg" alt="img">
  </div>

  <!-- The second column where the row and content will be nested -->

  <div class="col-md-9">

    <!-- Nested row -->
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">Home</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">About</div>

    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    This is where your text would go.
  </div>
</div>
```

Some more info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting